# Generate a random color of a list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So what I want to do is to take a list like this:

```
color1 = (225, 225, 0)
color2 = (225, 0, 225)
color3 = (0, 225, 225)
color4 = (0, 225, 0)
color5 = (225, 0, 0)
color6 = (0, 0, 225)
```

And choose a random one using the random module.

```
colors = random.choices(color1, color2)
```

But the problem here is that the randomizer takes just one number of the list, not the three that are in the brackets. Is there anyway to make that the randomizer takes all three
numbers so that I can use it in my program without any error.

Comment: `colors = random.choices([color1, color2])` (or `random.choices((color1, color2))`)

Comment: If you look up the documentation for `random.choices`, you'll find that what you were inadvertently doing the first time was to give it `(225, 225, 0)` as the choices, and `(225, 0, 225)` as the weights (hence it would have returned 225 and 0 with equal probability).

Comment: Use `random.choice` (non-plural) when you don't want the added capability of weighting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter of `random.choices` is a list of weights. You should not use it. The first parameter is a collection to choose from:

```
chosen_color = random.choices((color1, color2, colors, ...))
```

In fact, since you do not seem to worry about color names, there is no need to store them in separate variables. Put all colors in a tuple:

```
colors = ((225, 225, 0), (225, 0, 225), ...)
```

And choose from the tuple:

```
chosen_color = random.choices(colors)
```

Comment: It looks to me you are missing brackets in `colors = ...`

Comment: @rpanai It is permitted to omit them.

Comment: There is no need for them. A tuple is defined by commas, not brackets. But I put them back to make the code more readable.

Comment: There may be circumstances where the brackets are needed, but all I can currently think of is when the tuple is an argument in a function call. Not sure if there are others. (Edit: I guess when nested inside a list or another tuple.)

Comment: the first one didn't work for me because the output had also this bracket [], but the second worked so thanks.